# What development tools would you recommend for developing .NET apps in Mono that would give me the same productivity boost as Resharper?

Tags: mono, resharper, linux-development

Aside from using IDEs such as MonoDevelop, what combination of tools do you use in Mono development to give you the same productivity boost that one would normally gain by using R# in VS2010?

EDIT: I'm trying to kick the R# habit and switch to Mono development in Linux, but it's hard to kick the habit of using VS2010 + R#, and I need alternative tools to break that habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is none.  Here is [the same question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559887/is-there-a-resharper-like-addin-for-monodevelop).  Currently there are several [bounties offering a reward for a R# port to MonoDevelop](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/06/23/bounty-for-r-on-monodevelop/), but nothing yet, unfortunately.